# How to turn off default features of material design EditText in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I used material design 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0' in my Android app ( just to add password toggle for password field). I don't want other material features being included to my EditText.As you can see on the screenshot, blue line appears and also hint text goes up when PasswordEditText is touched. How can i get them rid of and leave only password toggle among material design features?

[image]

**XML of PasswordEditText:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_security_24"
    android:hint="Parol"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

- `android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"`

Update:

- `android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_security_24"`
- `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`

to:

- `app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_security_24"`
- `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"`

and use the standard features of the TextInputLayout to achieve the same layout:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerCircle"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/...."
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            app:placeholderText="Parol"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

with:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerCircle" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes:

1. Remove blue underline & use your own background:

You need to set `app:boxBackgroundMode="none"` to your `TextInputLayout`

**Edit:**
If this alone doesn't work then add to your `TextInputLayout`:

```
app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
```

2. To disable the floating hint:

You need to use `app:hintEnabled="false"` to your `TextInputLayout` & set the hint to `TextInputEditText`

So your final code would look like this: (Please add your background as I removed for testing)

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:hint="Parol"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done everything as you said. Floating hint has been removed, but line hasn't.  'app:boxBackgroundMode="none"' did not help.

Comment: @Jakhongir Try updated answer with `app:boxStrokeWidth` see if it makes any difference.